# Azure Functions with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, azure-functions

I use `project.json` to import `EntityFramework 6.1.3` NuGet package. I can confirm that the NuGet package is successfully restored in my function app.

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#package-management), I can directly use EntityFramework. However, I keep getting error like:

> ManualTriggerCSharp1: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

It seems that my function can't load the EntityFramework dll properly. Even though I copied both `EntityFramework.dll` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` into the `bin` directory, it still complains with the same exception.

What am I missing?

**Update**

Here's my `project.json` file:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Autofac": "4.2.0",
        "AutoMapper": "5.1.1",
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

As I mentioned above, this was not working. So, I manually copied both `EntityFramework.dll` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` into the `bin` directory and reference it within the `run.csx` file like:

```
#r "EntityFramework.dll"
#r "EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll"
```

But still complaining. The whole line of log message is:

> 2016-11-18T20:22:46.296 Exception while executing function: Functions.ManualTriggerCSharp1. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ManualTriggerCSharp1: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Update 2**

Here's my complete function code:

```
#r "Tournaments.EntityModels.dll"

using System;
using System.Configuration;

using Tournaments.EntityModels;

public static void Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {input}");

    var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TournamentDbContext"].ConnectionString;
    var dbContext = new TournamentDbContext(connString);
    var numberOfPlayers = dbContext.Players.ToList().Count;

    log.Info($"Number of Players: {numberOfPlayers}");
}
```

Note that `Tournaments.EntityModels.dll` is the actual database entity models. And here's my `project.json`:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to compile the function. There's no issue at all. The problem occurred at the runtime. when I ran this function, I got the error:

> 2016-11-19T00:52:40.818 Function started (Id=c03af3f2-38f5-4df9-9bc5-b5932c365c04)
>
> 2016-11-19T00:52:40.818 Function completed (Failure, Id=c03af3f2-38f5-4df9-9bc5-b5932c365c04)
>
> 2016-11-19T00:52:40.836 Exception while executing function: Functions.ManualTriggerCSharp3. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ManualTriggerCSharp3: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I looked into the logs in KUDU and found this from the logstream:

> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.454 Executing: 'Functions.ManualTriggerCSharp3' - Reason: 'This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.'
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.649 Function started (Id=b18b45a7-83a8-453e-a337-955e6a4a5117)
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.649 Function completed (Failure, Id=b18b45a7-83a8-453e-a337-955e6a4a5117)
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.649 A ScriptHost error has occurred
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.649 Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.649 Function started (Id=b18b45a7-83a8-453e-a337-955e6a4a5117)
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.649 Function completed (Failure, Id=b18b45a7-83a8-453e-a337-955e6a4a5117)
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.665 Exception while executing function: Functions.ManualTriggerCSharp3. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ManualTriggerCSharp3: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.665 Exception while executing function: Functions.ManualTriggerCSharp3. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ManualTriggerCSharp3: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.681 Exception while executing function: Functions.ManualTriggerCSharp3
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.696 Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.696 Executed: 'Functions.ManualTriggerCSharp3' (Failed)
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.696 Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.696 Function had errors. See Azure WebJobs SDK dashboard for details. Instance ID is 'b18b45a7-83a8-453e-a337-955e6a4a5117'
>
> 2016-11-19T01:00:25.696 Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

And here's the stack trace message from the function log:

> ...obs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.d__23.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`1.d__0.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__53.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__3b.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__36.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__1a.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I think I can provide all the necessary information I can here. Could you give me an advice, please?

Comment: Could you append project.json?

Comment: I haven't gotten automatic references with `project.json` packages working (in spite of the documentation). I just copy the dlls and reference them with `#r`.

Comment: Are you on the latest Functions runtime version (1.0)? I just tried myself and it worked fine. I added that package to project.json, and the package was automatically restored. I added the required EF using statements (no #r) and everything compiled.

Comment: @Youngjae Updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: @StephenCleary That's exactly what I did.

Comment: @mathewc Yep, I'm with the latest function version. Compilation itself is fine. When I actually ran the function, it threw that error.

Comment: Will take a look at this ASAP. As mentioned by @mathewc assemblies coming from package references are automatically referenced, so if you're unable to get that to work, we'll need to look at what is causing that and make sure it's addressed.

Comment: I just want to confirm since you have a couple of versions. Your current function uses the csx and project.json you have in update 2, correct? Might be worth throwing a quick repro together on GitHub to make sure we don't miss anything.

Comment: Just as @mathewc did, I used code similar to your function and the exact project.json and was able to compile and run the function using EF types (without an explicit `#r`). I believe the issue is when attempting to load the dependencies for your private assembly where the models are defined. How complex are your models and context? Is that something you can try to define in the function (maybe in a separate csx) to see if things work as expected? Any chance you can have a simple version of that assembly for a repro?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante Yes, I simplified my function to what I posted in the **Update 2** section. Sure. I'll extract a simple EF context and entity within a function and see how it's going. Then I'll leave a comment here again.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante It turned out my bad. I put wrong connectionstring - local db connection. Everything is totally fine now. However, the error message `could not load file or assembly ...` still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante Can we have more specific error messages here, instead of the `could not load file or assembly ...` message?

Comment: Glad to hear this is working as expected! Yeah, I agree, assembly load exception is indeed strange. Please do reach out if you see similar issues. I'll be working on some thorough documentation on the different kinds of references we support and putting some samples together soon.

Comment: @JustInChronicles How did you access the bin directory???

Comment: @TeeSee KUDU can help you to reach out to your bin directory.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps work for me on the latest Functions runtime (1.0). Create a new function (e.g. ManualTrigger), and use the "view files" UI to add a new `project.json` file with the following content:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

After saving the file you should see package restore happening in the functions log window, e.g.:

```
2016-11-18T16:50:05.772 Starting NuGet restore
2016-11-18T16:50:06.991 Restoring packages for D:\home\site\wwwroot\ManualTriggerCSharp2\project.json...
2016-11-18T16:50:07.553 Committing restore...
2016-11-18T16:50:07.569 Writing lock file to disk. Path: D:\home\site\wwwroot\ManualTriggerCSharp2\project.lock.json
2016-11-18T16:50:07.620 D:\home\site\wwwroot\ManualTriggerCSharp2\project.json
2016-11-18T16:50:07.620 Restore completed in 645ms.
2016-11-18T16:50:07.631 
2016-11-18T16:50:07.631 NuGet Config files used:
2016-11-18T16:50:07.631 C:\DWASFiles\Sites\function-fun\AppData\NuGet\NuGet.Config
2016-11-18T16:50:07.631 
2016-11-18T16:50:07.631 Feeds used:
2016-11-18T16:50:07.631 https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
2016-11-18T16:50:07.662 
2016-11-18T16:50:07.662 
2016-11-18T16:50:07.709 Packages restored.
```

After that you can simply add the EF using statements to your code and it will compile successfully:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Linq;

public static void Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {input}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @mathewc. As I left the comment on the question, I was able to compile the function itself. However, when I ran the code, it threw the exception.